# InternetExplorerDriver may have died - Selenium issue

Tags: selenium-grid, selenium-iedriver

I am using Selenium Grid to start an InternetExplorerDriver-Instance remotely. Therefore I use the following code:

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = (DesiredCapabilities) DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(getHubUrl()), capability);
```

At the second line of code there is a WebDriverException saying

> Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.

The remote machine is a Windows 7 system. I can't understand why this won't work?!

Comment: Have you tried killing the currently running hub and then restarting it again?

Comment: Is this question a duplicate of the following question? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023399/error-communicating-with-the-remote-browser-it-may-have-died-selenium-web-driv/25497994#25497994

Answer (score 0):

We have the same error on Windows 7 too but it works on Ubuntu.

What version of Selenium do you use, 2.20.0? Have you already tried to upgrade onto 2.21.0?

Answer (score 0):

Also, are you setting up the path to the InternetExplorerDriver? See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662241/selenium-is-not-able-to-launch-the-ie) here on SO - it helped me a lot launching the Google Chrome

Comment: All browsers (IE, Firefox, and Chrome as well) crash.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

I had the same problem running InternetExplorerDriver locally in Windows 7 - (IEDriverServer_Win32_2.42.0.zip)

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
```

When I checked the running processes under TaskManager, there were multiple `IEDriverServer.exe` processes running, that hadn't been cleaned up properly.

**Solution**

Running the following command, killed all running `IEDriverServer.exe` processes, and resolved this issue (for me).

```
taskkill /F /IM IEDriverServer.exe
```