# Selenium is not able to launch the IE.

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, selenium-grid

Selenium is not able to launch the IE.

`10:56:25,005 INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler] Command request: getNewBrowserSession[*iexploreproxy, http://192.168.132.105:8080/, ] on session null
10:56:25,005 INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory] creating new remote session
10:56:25,005 INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory] Allocated session 9fa93fe865904e3da895c91a86ebdcb0 for http://192.168.132.105:8080/, launching...
10:56:25,005 INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.WindowsProxyManager] Modifying registry settings...
10:56:25,474 INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.InternetExplorerCustomProxyLauncher] Launching Internet Explorer...`

After the `Internet Explorer...` it won't respond. Please help me in fixing this issue.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How are you starting the hub and the node?

For the node, this worked for me:

1. Download InternetExplorerDriver from http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list to c:\Selenium
2. Download Selenium stand alone server(selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar) from http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list to c:\Selenium
3. Start the node: `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://192.168.1.248:4444/grid/register -browser browserName="internet explorer",version=8.0,platform=WINDOWS -Dwebdriver.internetexplorer.driver=c:\Selenium\InternetExplorerDriver.exe`

I am using OSX to run the hub, Virtual Box to run Windows 7 Home and the IE hub.

Also, make sure that the Protected Mode settings are the same for all zones.

Comment: Do you need the internet explorer driver for selenium grid tests? I can run my test in IE without it (using selenium webdriver, grid 2)

Comment: been looking for the -browser syntax for quite some time.  Thank you so much for adding it to your "starting the node".

Answer (score -1):

```
Lets consider Hub running on Machine-A whose IPAddress is = 192.168.10.10 default port no. 4444.
Lets Node running on Machine-B whose IPAddress is = 192.168.10.20.
Lets consider operating System on HUB and Node is installed on drive C:\ (C-Drive). 
create a folder named selenium on c:\ as c:\selenium.
keep binaries of IExplorer.exe, chromeDriver.exe and Selenium-Standalone-server2.10.0.jar. (on both machine A and B).

configuring HUB on Machine-A
1- open Command prompt 
2- go to folder selenium using 
         i type cd\ then enter
         ii  type c:  then enter
         iii c:> cd selenium then enter
3- java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar -role hub

Configuring NOde on Machine - B
1- open Command prompt 
2- go to folder selenium using 
         i type cd\ then enter
         ii  type c:  then enter
         iii c:> cd selenium then enter
3- java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.10.10:4444/grid/register  -port 5560 -browser  browserName=internt explore,maxInstance=4,version=10,platform=WINDOWS  -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=c:\selenium\IEDriver.exe

your node will get register with Hub on port 5560.

Test Case will become as- 

package testCase;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class Avinash_Internet_Explore 
{

    WebDriver driver;
    String baseUrl , nodeUrl;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception 
    {
        nodeUrl = "http://192.168.10.20:5560/wd/hub"; //Machine-A IPAdress  
                                                     with Port No.          

        DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();

        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeUrl),capability);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception 
    {
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException
    {

        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");     
        Thread.sleep(3000);     
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000); 
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("aavinashpande@gmail.com");

        driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("********");

        driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();

        Thread.sleep(6000);
    }

}
```