# Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died. Selenium Web driver

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is my error log:

```
Apr 12, 2014 3:27:46 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: Permission denied: connect
Apr 12, 2014 3:27:46 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect
Apr 12, 2014 3:27:46 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: Permission denied: connect
Apr 12, 2014 3:27:46 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect
Apr 12, 2014 3:27:46 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: Permission denied: connect
Apr 12, 2014 3:27:46 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:18:15'
System info: host: 'prgi-PC', ip: '192.168.1.9', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:589)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:268)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.findElements(RemoteWebElement.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.findElementsByTagName(RemoteWebElement.java:264)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByTagName.findElements(By.java:323)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.findElements(RemoteWebElement.java:163)
    at com.sai.kiran.Test.main(Test.java:155)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:83)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:117)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:178)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.fallBackExecute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:322)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:301)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.execute(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:165)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$LazyCommandExecutor.execute(FirefoxDriver.java:362)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:568)
    ... 6 more
```

**CODE:**

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

String path="C:\\Users\\prgi\\Downloads\\listShack";
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", path);

profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);

profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/msword,application/csv,text/csv,image/png ,image/jpeg");

profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",
false);

profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting",
false);
//profile.setPreference("browser.download.useDownloadDir",true);
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force",
false);

profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);

profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", false);

profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", false);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.useWindow",
false);

profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);

profile.setPreference("services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",
false);

profile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

and from here I am managing my elements..

note: It worked two days continuously 24/7 and today I am getting this error frequently.

Comment: All we have is the stack trace here. Please provide more info to increase your chances of getting an answer. What code (small chunk of it) reproduces this issue? What changed in the system between when it worked and when it failed? Have you tried running this on a fresh system? Does it fail there?

Comment: Also, given that you received a permission denied error, did u check if your firewall is blocking selenium?

Comment: i am working on the same system and i dnt think my firewall is blocking selenium.

you want me to show my code what i have written @Vish

Comment: Please double check that your firewall is indeed not the issue. Random failures typically point at this kind of stuff. And yeah, code is needed - but dont go overboard, only paste the code thats needed.

Comment: That exception on its own could be anything: from driver compatibility issues to network problems. So stack trace is not helpful in this case. 
If you are using RemoteWebDriver to run tests remotely from machine A to machine B, then try to run them locally on machine B. And if you are not running tests remotely, try to see what happens if you use WebDriver and not remote driver (not a hard switch). Will help you to eliminate networking issues and driver issues

Comment: i am not using remote web driver , i am calling as

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

Comment: Is the following question a duplicate of this question? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727655/internetexplorerdriver-may-have-died-selenium-issue/25497982

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Problem**

I had the same problem running InternetExplorerDriver locally in Windows 7 - (IEDriverServer_Win32_2.42.0.zip)

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
```

When I checked the running processes under TaskManager, there were multiple `IEDriverServer.exe` processes running, that hadn't been cleaned up properly.

**Solution**

Running the following command, killed all running `IEDriverServer.exe` processes, and resolved this issue (for me).

```
taskkill /F /IM IEDriverServer.exe
```

Comment: Do you happen to know what the Firefox version is?

Comment: @Fallenreaper ... er... for my scenario, I had the same exception, but using InternetExplorer instead of Firefox... so no Firefox, just InternetExplorer.

Comment: seems one of the known selenium issue https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/4319

Comment: im getting the same error while running firefox / chrome on ubuntu. How to resolve this issue on ubuntu?

Comment: @NisrineBouGhannam - if you want to kill processes in Ubuntu, there's plenty of info on the internet - e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/104903/how-do-i-kill-processes-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I followed these steps and the problem got resolved:

1. get the firefox profile name

   - try this command on run window firefox.exe -P
     **or** 
     firefox.exe -P
     **or**
     firefox.exe -profilemanager

One of the above command will open pop up stating the name of Default profile which is nomaly "default"

2. Use below mentioned code for gettingthe firefox driver

   ```
   ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
   FirefoxProfile myProfile = allProfiles.getProfile("default");
   myProfile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
   myProfile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(true);
   driver = new FirefoxDriver(myProfile);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For me using a port starting with a 1, rather than a port close to the default port value 5555, caused me to have this error.  Changing the node port from 1234 back to 5558 has solved the issue. Not sure how ports work but it seems 1234 was unstable

Answer (score -3):

Please try to replace exe path with below command

```
File file = new File("IE DriverServer.exe path");
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
```