# UnreachableBrowserException

Tags: java, eclipse, webdriver

Using Eclipse and Selenium Webdriver

Im using this @AfterMethod to close my browser after each test.

```
@AfterMethod
public void closeBrowser(ITestResult result) {
    result.getMethod().getMethodName();
    endTest(testName);
    getDriver().getCurrentUrl();

    getDriver().quit(); // Close browser before each new test
}
```

However I get this message for both Chrome and IE

org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.48.1', revision: 'd80083d', time: '2015-10-08 21:07:25'

I have closed out the old processes in the task manager as well and cleaned my output folder and I keep getting this error. Please help!

Comment: I think you are using the same driver instance in some other class as well. Or you could check manually that when closing the window there is no additional dialog appearing.

Comment: Sorry I am not exactly sure what you mean, can you ellaborate

Comment: Sometime the instances are still running even if you close the explorer windows. You can go to task manager and verify if the instances are running there hidden. Please have a look here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023399/error-communicating-with-the-remote-browser-it-may-have-died-selenium-web-driv/25497994#25497994). Furthermore, try to restart your pc, sometimes it works too.

Comment: Yes I did make mention of that in my question. I have closed out all the old processes and restarted my computer, this happens every time whether its the first time i have attempted the process or 5th time.

Comment: Try getDriver.close();

Comment: This works, and the test now passes but the webdrivers aren't closing in the task manager which will create a problem down the line once entired suites are going to be ran, any suggesttions?

Comment: You can have a look at my suggestion below in the answer section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to close the windows:

```
getDriver.close();
```

Furthermore for your second question, you can try to kill the background instances like:

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM IEDriverServer.exe");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You can replace IEDriverServer.exe with your process name. And accept the answer if it helped you in any way.

Comment: I have a follow up to this question. While it did solve my issue of closing the webrowser out of the task list I can no longer run multiple tests I get the error "Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure."