# Not able to select from dropdown - Selenium Webdriver

Tags: html, selenium

I am trying to select the value SYSTEM CLASS from the dropdown but I am unable to do so. Each time, I get a `NoSuchElement` exception of the `ElementNotVisible` exception. 
Please find the HTML Code below : -

```
<select class="gwt-ListBox">
  <option value="(Please select)">(Please select)</option>
  <option value="SYSTEM CLASS">SYSTEM CLASS</option>
</select>
```

Also, Below is the selenium code I tried using to select from the dropdown :-

Code set 1 -

```
WebElement dropDown = driver.findElement(By.className("gwt-ListBox"));
dropDown.click();
Thread.sleep(10000);
WebElement dropDownOptions = driver.findElement(By.id("country-codes-menu-1"));
dropDownOptions.findElement(By.name("SYSTEM CLASS")).click();
```

Code Set 2 -

```
WebElement CustClassDropDown = driver.findElement(By.className("gwt-ListBox"));
WebElement CustClassDropDown = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='main']/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/select"));
Select className = new Select(CustClassDropDown);
className.selectByVisibleText("SYSTEM CLASS");
```

Code Set 3 -

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.className("gwt-ListBox"))).selectByVisibleText("SYSTEM CLASS");
Thread.sleep(1000)
```

Each Time I run either of the three scripts, I am getting below exception : -

> FAILED: createCustomer
>       org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
>       Command duration or timeout: 20.04 seconds
>       Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:32:46'
>       System info: host: 'ABHISHEP-IN', ip: '10.176.250.119', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_111'
>       Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
>       Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=46.0,
>   platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true,
>   browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true,
>   cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
>       Session ID: 1f9d091d-b977-4ebe-8ccd-efc82d10033c

Request you to kindly suggest how to select the values from the dropdown. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some more information as: 1. Is it a normal Dropdown or a Boot Strapped Dropdown? 2. Can you provide a snapshot of the Dropdown menu? 3. Can you provide some more relevant HTML DOM?

Answer (score 0):

Try the Following:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//select[@class='gwt-ListBox']"))).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//option[@value='SYSTEM CLASS']"))).click();
```

Comment: I Tried the above code but then, I am getting a different exception this time -

Comment: List box is opening? You getting error at ? `dropDown ` or  `dropDownOptions `

Comment: I tried using the above code. The list box is opening but I am ending up getting Unreachable browser exception - org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.

Comment: You checking it on Remote?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023399/error-communicating-with-the-remote-browser-it-may-have-died-selenium-web-driv

Comment: @JeffC :  I am not telling to use Thread.sleep() on regular basis. Please don't just downvote due to that reason. There are many implicit wait which you can use. But for sake of making sure that other things works I keep on using it.

Comment: There's no reason to use it here and it's a bad practice which makes this answer not useful. If you know the right way to do it, then use that instead of sleep.

Comment: Hope it is useful now. @JeffC

Comment: I edited your question. The `wait.until()` returns the element waited for so you don't need to wait for the element, scrape it off the page again, and then click it. You can do the above more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell why it's not visible. You may need to wait for it to become visible or it may be that it's a hidden SELECT backing a fake dropdown. Try this...

```
WebElement select = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("select.gwt-ListBox")));
new Select(select).selectByVisibleText("SYSTEM CLASS");
```

Comment: I would like to disagree with you. If it is a normal Dropdown the entire Select options are present in the DOM once the page loads. It doesn't makes any sense to me to add an Explicit wait for a select option at all. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Dev I'm not waiting for the OPTIONS to load, I'm waiting for the SELECT to be clickable... in the DOM, visible, and able to be clicked.

Comment: I have searched in stackoverflow.com and in many other forums to check if there is a possibility of a Select item to be unclickable even after the DOM is loaded, which would have made sense to me to use the Explicit Wait for `elementToBeClickable`. IMO, a Select item is always to be selected and can't have unclickable/clickable states. The only way to make it unselectable is to `Disable` it forcefully. Unfortunately I havn't found any reference of a select item to be unclickable in any of the forums. Can you guide me further to some discussion threads to support your argument? Thanks.

Comment: OP said that the element is not visible which indicates to me that it might be an issue where once the page is done loading the element would be made visible. Checking to see if it's clickable is just a way to wait until it's ready to be interacted with... it could just as well be wait until visible.

Comment: Thanks. It is petty apparent from the OP's question that he/she is a beginner with #selenium & #html hashtags. Though the error says about `ElementNotVisibleException` but the reason can be different. The element may be on a frame/iframe. Hence the exception. But I still wonder how can a `select` item be unselectable even after the DOM is loaded so we have to induce Explicit Wait? Can you guide to any documentation please?

Comment: The error wouldn't be `ElementNotVisibleException` if the element was in an iframe. We don't know that the DOM is loaded. There can be dynamic portions of the page that aren't loaded when the browser returns 'document.readyState==complete', thus the use of `WebDriverWait`.

Comment: are you suggesting that there can be a time difference of 10 seconds (as per your code) between loading of the parent `Select` element & child `Option` elements?

Comment: As I said before, the wait is not waiting for the OPTIONS to load... it's waiting for the SELECT to load. That said, there can be AJAX calls that load OPTIONS dynamically and those can take a long time. I'm not addressing that with my answer though.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question: can there be a time difference of 10 seconds (as per your code) between loading of the parent `Select` element & child `select` elements which is supposed be present in the DOM (generally) even after browser returns 'document.readyState==complete' in normal condition? (Lets leave aside AJAX calls for a seperate discussion)

Answer (score 0):

How about this..

```
Select cmb = new Select(driver.findElement(By.ClassName("gwt-ListBox")));
```

Then

```
cmb.selectByValue("SYSTEM CLASS");
```

OR

```
cmb.selectByIndex(1);
```